# Moq caches return value

Tags: moq

Seems like Moq is caching data I set up as return. When I do this:

```
var service = new Mock<AlbumService>();
service.Setup(x => x.CreateOne()).Returns(new AlbumService().CreateOne());
```

it returns **the same** object even thought AlbumService.CreateOne() returns new Album instance.

Is it possible to make Moq call the Returns Action every time I access CreateOne() ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This ought to help:

```
var service = new Mock<AlbumService>();
service.Setup(x => x.CreateOne()).Returns(() => new AlbumService().CreateOne());
```

To elaborate, the Returns method accepts an object of the return type or a delegate that will evaluate to the return type. The delegate is invoked whenever the mocked method is invoked.